# My Google Sign In Was Working Perfectly On MY Android App now it gives error code "10"

Tags: android, google-signin

I am working on an Android app and the Google Sign In was working perfectly fine. Due to some hardware problem, I had to reinstall Windows after that when I tried the new APK the app started throwing error giving the code: 10.

I tried uploading a new SHA-1 key to Firebase Console.
I Even Created a dummy app in which the Google Sign is working fine.

```
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient; //globally defined
```

in onCreateMethod() i am using  this

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END config_signin]

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }

    }

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            //login="2";
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            //updateUI(account);
            Log.i("Email", account.getEmail());
            Log.i("Display Name", account.getDisplayName());
            Log.i("First Name", account.getFamilyName());
            Log.i("Given Name", account.getGivenName());
            Log.i("Profile", account.getPhotoUrl().toString());
            Log.i("Token", account.getId());
            progressDialog.show();
            final Thread t = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int jumpTime = 0;
                    while (jumpTime < totalprogressTime) {

                        try {
                            sleep(3000
                            );
                            jumpTime += 5;
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
            GOOGLElogIn(account.getEmail(),"1",account.getDisplayName(),account.getIdToken(),logintype);
            //,login,
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.e("Google SignIn", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());

            //show toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to do Sign In : " + e.getStatusCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //updateUI(null);
        }
    }
go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isGuest=false;
                logintype = "3";
                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQ_CODE);
            }
        });
```

Console Log Shows This

```
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1110, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4507256814460934916}]
V/FA: onActivityCreated
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=LoginActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=4507256814460934916, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignInHubActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4507256814460934917}]
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 620052166
    Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 97
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 620052199
E/Google SignIn: signInResult:failed code=10
```

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @IntelliJ Amiya github link its shows that Error code 10 is DEVELOPER_ERROR.

There is 3 issue you need to check

1. SHA1 and Package Name in the Google API console
2. Check GoogleSignInOptions
3. The web client ID (if you're using it) belongs to the same project where you registered your package name and SHA1.